# What Did Basara Do to Mio to relieve the curse?

Tags: shinmai-mao-no-testament

In the anime Mio falls under an aphrodisiac curse by Maria using the "*Reversed*" Master-Servant Pact which is triggered by the servant's **Distrust** to his/her Master

On [Episode Five](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_Testament_of_Sister_New_Devil_episodes) of the anime,

> Following Yahiro's defeat, Basara wakes up with Maria lying on top of him while seducing him, encountering Mio naked in the bathroom while getting caught in an awkward position, Yuki offering herself to bathe with Basara, and Mio yet again falling into a pleasure-driven curse.

After the scene Basara lift Mio and said going to her room. The scene then is cut (eventhough its uncersored version) the nezxt thing they are eating at a restaurant. so what happened in between these scenes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Scene you want to see is showed in the restaurant scene as flashback while Basara and his friend is talking about the Master- Servant Pact.

Are You sure you have the Uncensored version. I watched the anime and here is the screenshot of scene flashback from the episode following the restaurant scene.

[image]

[image]

Also there is also a special Episode, ShinMai Maouno TEstament Special 3 one of the Specials included on the Blu-ray/DVD volumes. Chibi versions of Mio and Maria narrate Basara's various erotic encounters.

[image]

Here is a Screenshot of the Third Special Episode (Narration of Episode 5's Erotic Event)

ALso Zhi Heng's Observation and answer is quite Correct. Basara did what he have to do to stop the activation of Mio's curse.

Answer (score -1):

Well, from my close observations, Basara fondled her breasts to give her some sort of "pleasure" so that the curse will stop.